# External Storage not showing on Nautilus

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I am having issues with flash drives, external disk drives and Android phone storage.

I have a laptop and desktop both running Ubuntu 18.04 and mounting either of them seems to be a hit and miss especially with the laptop. 70% of the time they will not show up on Nautilus unless I do a reboot of the OS.

When I run lsusb the devices show but not mounted on Nautilus.

Googled and one answer was to do with USB autosuspend also added this line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1" to grub though it hasn't resolved the issue.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: You can check if your device is mounted using the command `mount`. Especially for android phones, it will be mounted only if/after your phone is unlocked. For USB flash drives (and externs disks), it depends on the permissions. For more details, look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) Ubuntu official guide.